# Query is inserting random stuff into db table?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've connected to the database so i understand my connection is fine and i'm also using MVC and PDO, however when inserting into the table it's giving me random values rather than the values actual set from the post variables for example in my table under each column its inserting '1''s there rather than the values been set. This is my code:

This is the function in my register class:

```
    public function signup($email,$password,$firstname,$lastname,$mobile){


    $query = 'INSERT INTO testing (username, password, first_name, last_name, mobile) VALUES (:email, :password, :firstname, :lastname, :mobile)';

    //putting it in a variable
    $statement = $this->_dbHandle->prepare($query);

     //variables
    $statement->bindParam(':email', $email);
    $statement->bindParam(':password', $password);
    $statement->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname);
    $statement->bindParam(':lastname', $lastname);
    $statement->bindParam(':mobile', $mobile);


    // Then execute the query
    $statement->execute();


    return $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


  }
```

this is where im passing the parameters from (my register.php controller):

```
<?php
require_once("Models/reg.php");
require_once("Views/register.phtml");
$view = new stdClass();
$view->pageTitle = 'Register';


$registerUser = new reg();


if(isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["password"]) && isset($_POST["firstname"]) && isset($_POST["lastname"]) && isset($_POST["mobile"]))
{
$registerQuery = $registerUser->signup(isset($_POST["email"]),isset($_POST["password"]),isset($_POST["firstname"]),isset($_POST["lastname"]),isset($_POST["mobile"]));
}
```

And in my phtml file I have text boxes with names such as "email", "password", "firstname", "lastname", "mobile"

Does anyone understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you confirmed the contents of the post variables are correct before you commit them to the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isset($_POST["email"])` returns 1 (or 0 if false)
 so you get what you tell it to put in the db simply remove the isset()s

```
if(isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["password"]) && isset($_POST["firstname"]) && isset($_POST["lastname"]) && isset($_POST["mobile"]))
{
$registerQuery = $registerUser->signup($_POST["email"],$_POST["password"],$_POST["firstname"],$_POST["lastname"],$_POST["mobile"]);
}
```